# Using Google Cloud Endpoints for iOS app build on Swift language

Tags: ios, swift, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new to iOS development, started learning and developing iOS app with Swift language, now wanted to use Google Cloud Endpoints as back-end. All the tutorials/discussions/guides are referring to Objective-C libraries. Can someone share ideas on how to use Google Cloud Endpoints with Swift language or refer tutorials. I am good at Google App Engine and Java.

Comment: It's possible to call the endpoints directly over https. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30886913/2295256. Also the following sample app (https://github.com/soundTricker/swift-cloud-endpoint-sample) uses the objective-c client lib

Comment: Thank you..!!! So, just to confirm. What i understood is, even the client library is generated in object-c we can use those api's  through Swift right?

Answer (score 1):

[Swift can use Objective C libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). So in theory, you can generate an Objective C client library and use it with your Swift iOS app. You could also use a Swift JSON library and make the HTTP calls yourself. You can see the form of the HTTP calls using API Explorer, which you get to by visiting `yourapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I successfully tried Google Cloud EndPoints, i could able to generate <Class>EndPoints and client libraries for android and using rpc/rest discovery classes, i generated IOS client libraries. But when i tried to add the IOS Client libraries to IOS App, lot of dependencies errors like GTMSessionFetcher or HttpSessoinFetcher kind of issues. I decided not to use Google Cloud Endpoints. Instead just depend on RESTful services.